# "permission denied" when trying to open serial connection

Tags: r, serial-port

I am using the serial package in R to read a serial input to USB (COM3). When i try to open/read the connection:

```
library(serial)
con <- serialConnection(name="test_con", port="COM3", mode="4, n, 8, 1", ...)
open(con)
read.serialConnection(con)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: object 'binned_spikes' not found
```

Sometimes open(con) works but read.serialConnection() never does.

I have tried restarting my computer etc. and have tested the serial connection on Teraterm and the device definitely works and is in the right port. Ive also tried this for all 4 ports and always get the same error message in R.

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: Why does the title not match the text?

Comment: I believe the name argument for the serialConnection argument is trivial but I will check this when I get back on Thursday.

Comment: Have checked this and it makes no difference